# Retrieve user input from browser to use in controller for a third party query string rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm simply trying to get a users input into my rails controller from my `form_tag`.

the general idea is a user enters some text in the `text_field_tag`

***app/views/pages/home.html.erb***

```
<div>
   <%= form_tag root_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil, class: 'submit' %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

I have some JavaScript in place to take the params and append them to the current
url in the browser.

***/main/app/assets/javascript/table.js***

```
function appendParamToUrl() {
   var pages = '';
   var term = $('#search').val();
   window.history.pushState( pages, 'url', '?search=' + term );
}
```

I then try to retrieve those params from the rails controller to add to a query string to make an api call to a third party.

```
def home
        term = params[:search]
        @stats = HTTParty.get("https://api.ritekit.com/v1/stats/history/#{term}?tags=&client_id=81c7fa4e99adc98e9455c86ee38a4c1bbe3f97328732")
        gon.queries = @stats
end
```

Rails console show the correct params

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=trump" for 148.75.220.61 at 2018-08-21 00:28:49 +0000
Cannot render console from 148.75.220.61! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PagesController#home as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"trump"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1182ms (Views: 71.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

But when `term = params[:search]` comes up as `nil` unless I reload page, the params stay in the browser and then intended result happens. The data retrieved is used to populate a datatable I have setup.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *But when term = params[:search] comes up as nil unless I reload page, the params stay in the browser and then intended result happens.* - can you say more about this, please.

Comment: Try replacing `window.history.pushState()` with `window.location = window.location.href + '?search=' + term;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to retrieve `term = params[:search]` in your controller which will get value from the `form_tag` part since this is a remote form, you need to setup something like below:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

And you can append desired data to your table in this `home.js.erb` file now. You don't need to write a JavaScript function like `appendParamToUrl`.

See [2 Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript)

---UPDATE---
`<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>` This line will get the value in url when page load, so the first time, params[:search] is nil. And when you hit the submit button, the server will get confused, because you have two params[:search], one is in url, and another is text_field_tag.
You need to determine which one you need to get first.
How about change search to query in url then you can inspect both param[:query] and param[:search] in your controller, I am sure one of them has a non-nil value.

Comment: How does `format.js` fix `nil` value of `params[:search]`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I read the problem again, and I found your might have two problems in this simple action. Use Unobtrusive JavaScript can help your walkthrough the Rails Ajax part.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I was able to resolve the `nil` issue by creating a custom action in my controller and it was able to get the search query from `params[:search]`. Thanks for introducing me to the concept of unobtrusive JS and the `respond_to` method. I was able to get rid of the `appendParamToUrl` function I had in my table.js file as suggested. Thanks everyone for getting me through this issue.